# regex to not match particular word but match other patterns

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm working with clinical notes and as part of preprocessing, I would like to replace the various ways of expressing age to a single token. For example, "Patient is a 30 year old male", I'd like to replace it with "Patient is 30 year_old male". There are many ways this "year old" is written in a clinical note and I'm trying capture as much of them.

I am using Python's re module. Currently I have:

```
# matches: y.o., y/o, years old. year old, yearold
s = re.sub(r'(\w*)y\.?\/?(o|ears|ear)\.? ?(old)? ?', r'\1 year_old ', s)
```

With this I'm able to match: y.o., years old, yearold, year old, yo, y/o, 24yearold, 24years old. Unfortunately, just the word "year" and "years" also match. So, "nine years ago" becomes "nine year_old ago". I'd like to avoid matching "years" and "year" and match other patterns that I've specified. How would I do this? My search tells me I have to use negative lookahead but I'm not sure how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Your problem statement is basically flawed. You are looking for "years" except when it's followed by something, but "old" is fine and many other things are probably fine too.  You could *torturedly* come up with a list of things it cannot be followed by, like `years?(?! (?:ago|since|until|...))` but this sounds like an uphill battle.

Comment: (Oh that regex is flawed too, it will decice "year" is fine in the phrase "24 years ago" because if it doesn't match the `s` then it's not followed by space, "ago".)

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll have to split the regex up.

Comment: @shaun does [`(\d+)(?: ?(?:years? ?old|y[ .\/]*o\.?))`](https://regex101.com/r/mvTKIt/1) work for you?

Comment: @ctwheels Wow! That works, awesome. Probably will never encounter this but changing \d+ to \w+ changes "fifty years old" to "fifty year_old". Thank you for your help!

Comment: @shaun I've posted it as an answer and stepped through each part of the regex pattern to explain it. Let me know if you have any further questions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/mvTKIt/1)

```
(\d+)(?: ?(?:years? ?old|y[ .\/]*o\.?))
```

- `(\d+)` Capture one or more digits into capture group 1
- `(?: ?(?:years? ?old|y[ .\/]*o\.?))` Match the following

  - `?` Optionally match a space (between the digit and *year old* text)
  - `(?:years? ?old|y[ .\/]*o\.?)` Match either of the following

    - `years? ?old` Matches `year`, optionally matches `s`, optionally matches a space, matches `old`. So it matches the following:

      - `years old`
      - `yearsold`
      - `year old`
      - `yearold`
    - `y[ .\/]*o\.?` Matches `y`, then any number of spaces, `.`, or `/`, then `o`, then `.`. So it matches the following (plus more):

      - `y.o.`
      - `y.o`
      - `yo`
      - `y/o`
      - `y/o.`
      - `y./o.`
      - `y o`
      - `y. o.`

To allow this to match even more, you may enable the case insensitive `i` flag so that it matches uppercase variants as well, such as `Y.O.` or `Years Old`.

Comment: To avoid false positive, I'll add word boundaries after `old` in the first branch and after `o` in the second.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Could you indicate the modified regex? Is it just this: (\d+)(?: ?(?:years? ?old\b|y[ .\/]*o\b\.?))

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thank you for catching that! "Copy of" got replaced by "Cop years_oldf". But once I added \b after o, that didn't happen. However, the original pattern is not captured as well :(